# How to make the navbar navigate to something and then automatically close right after? Bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am writing code for my website, and i have a problem with the navbar in bootstrap. Once i click something, it navigates to the side of the page that i want it to (thats intended), but the navbar doesnt close right after. It just stays there and it has to be clicked again in order to close it, which is really annoying for phone users, because they dont see half of the screen. How can i make it so that it closes after i click something?

```
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark pt-lg-3 sticky-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="index.html"><img src="/images/solveco.png" width="300" height="100" alt="" /></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-3 mb-lg-0 fs-5">
          <li class="nav-item mx-lg-2">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#">Home <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-lg-2">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#about">Über uns <i class="fa-solid fa-address-card"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-lg-2">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#kontakt">Kontakt <i class="fa-solid fa-phone"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-lg-2">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#faq">FAQ <i class="fa-solid fa-question"></i></a>

          <li class="d-flex align-items-center mx-lg-2 mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <a href="x" target="_blank" class="icon-link text-white" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"
              title="Folge uns auf Facebook!">
              <i class="fab fa-facebook fa-lg me-2 mx-lg-2"></i></a>

            <a href="x" target="_blank" class="icon-link text-white" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"
              title="Folge uns auf Twitter!">
              <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-lg mx-2"></i></a>

            <a href="x" target="_blank" class="icon-link text-white" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"
              title="Folge uns auf Instagram!">
              <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-lg mx-2"></i></a>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

I tried using the data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show", it worked, but then the navigation doesnt work, so whenever i press it, the navbar closes without navigating to the specific side of the page (its a onepager).

Comment: What do you mean by "click something" - you mean clicking menu items, isn't that `href` redirects to another HTML page or you're making a on-page navbar?

Comment: its a one pager, so esentially, it should just move me to a different section of the site. Not a different html page, example would be something like "Contact", one i press it, it should move me to where the contact details are, which in this case, are on the bottom of the page.

Comment: It's better to add your full code or a Minimal, Reproducible Example (a small example of it).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add: **data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show"** to each li in the menu.

```html
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-3 mb-lg-0 fs-5">
          <li class="nav-item mx-lg-2">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show">Home <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-lg-2">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#about" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show">Über uns <i class="fa-solid fa-address-card"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-lg-2">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#kontakt" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show">Kontakt <i class="fa-solid fa-phone"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item mx-lg-2">
            <a class="nav-link text-white" href="#faq" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse.show">FAQ <i class="fa-solid fa-question"></i></a>

          <li class="d-flex align-items-center mx-lg-2 mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <a href="x" target="_blank" class="icon-link text-white" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"
              title="Folge uns auf Facebook!">
              <i class="fab fa-facebook fa-lg me-2 mx-lg-2"></i></a>

            <a href="x" target="_blank" class="icon-link text-white" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"
              title="Folge uns auf Twitter!">
              <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-lg mx-2"></i></a>

            <a href="x" target="_blank" class="icon-link text-white" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"
              title="Folge uns auf Instagram!">
              <i class="fab fa-instagram fa-lg mx-2"></i></a>

          </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: i did that, but then the navigation doesnt work, its a one pager, so the href="#" doesnt move me to the parts of the website, it just laggs and stays in one place after i click the options, navbar closes perfectly but yeah, it doesnt move :/

Comment: I tried this and it worked. Maybe you could share your complete code. Take a look at the Codeply example here https://www.codeply.com/p/eFzDCcVSC2 (Only in the 'about' option).